# If date is in range then assign a value Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

If Date is in the range of 12 to 20 then assign a value corresponding to it and if it is in the range of 26 to 5 the assign another value.

Below is the Example

| Crawl_date | Seller A |
| --- | --- |
| 12/28/2021 | Harry |
| 12/29/2021 | Cat |
| 01/03/2022 | Harry |
| 01/04/2022 | Cat |
| 01/16/2022 | Harry |
| 01/16/2022 | Cat |
| 01/17/2022 | Harry |
| 01/18/2022 | Cat |
| 02/17/2022 | Harry |
| 02/18/2022 | Cat |

My Expected output would be as below -

| Crawl_date | Seller A | Crawl_date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/28/2021 | Harry | Jan-A |
| 12/29/2021 | Cat | Jan-A |
| 01/03/2022 | Harry | Jan-A |
| 01/04/2022 | Cat | Jan-A |
| 01/16/2022 | Harry | Jan-B |
| 01/16/2022 | Cat | Jan-B |
| 01/17/2022 | Harry | Jan-B |
| 01/18/2022 | Cat | Jan-B |
| 02/17/2022 | Harry | Feb-B |
| 02/18/2022 | Cat | Feb-B |

Create a new column "Crawl_date 2" and assign a similar value (Jan-A) if it is in the range of 26th  to 5th and if it is in the range of 12th to 20th then assign another value(Jan-B).

if it nears to start of the month then assign the Month name followed by A and if it is in the middle of the month then assign the Month name followed by B.

Like for the last row it was in the middle of Feb month then assign the Month name followed by B. (Feb-B)

Comment: Hi @DavidBacci if it nears to start of the month then assign Month name followed by A and if it is in the middle of month then assign Month name followed by B.

Comment: Is December correct according to your rules?

Comment: @DavidBacci Sorry, It should be Jan instead of Dec.

Comment: No David, First row should be JAN instead of Dec

Comment: But what is the rule? You said: "if it nears to start of the month then assign the Month name followed by A and if it is in the middle of the month then assign the Month name followed by B." First row is in Dec. If the month is Dec, do you want it made into Jan?

Comment: Yes, it should be Jan because the date is near to Jan. So, I would like to consider it under Jan.Also VAR d = DAY('Table'[Crawl_date]) which you have mentioned "Crawl_date" is the column and it is not accepting it.

Comment: Replace 'Table'[Crawl_date] with the name of your table and the name of your column

Comment: Can you please update Dec to Jan. Is it possible?

Comment: I am checking it. Thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: @DavidBacci Thank you so much, Sir. Your code is working fine.

Comment: @DavidBacci Thank you so much, Sir. Your code is working fine.
I have one more condition, suppose we need to add the Year as well then what do we need to do?
Ex- In the first row instead of Jan-A if we need 2023Jan-A. Can you please suggest me this? Also, we need to take care of the year change here last days of Dec will be treated as next Year. As for 28-Dec-2021 the output should be 2022Jan-A.

Comment: I'll update the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Requirement**

```
Crawl_date 2 = 
VAR d = DAY('Table'[Crawl_date])
RETURN 

SWITCH(TRUE(), 
d >=26 && d <= 31 ,FORMAT( DATEADD( 'Calendar'[Date], 1, MONTH),"yyyy")& FORMAT( DATEADD( 'Calendar'[Date], 1, MONTH),"mmm")& "-A",
d >=1 && d <= 5  , FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"yyyy") &FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"mmm") & "-A",
d >=12 && d <=20,FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"yyyy") & FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"mmm") & "-B",
BLANK()
)
```

Create a brand new table as follows:

```
Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()
```

This creates a calendar table for you.

Create an exact relationship as follows:

[image]

Add the following calculated column:

```
Crawl_date 2 = 
VAR d = DAY('Table'[Crawl_date])
RETURN 

SWITCH(TRUE(), 
d >=26 && d <= 31 , FORMAT( DATEADD( 'Calendar'[Date], 1, MONTH),"mmm")& "-A",
d >=1 && d <= 5  , FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"mmm") & "-A",
d >=12 && d <=20, FORMAT('Table'[Crawl_date],"mmm") & "-B",
BLANK()
)
```

[image]